# How to periodically schedule a task django celery

Tags: python, django, celery

```
# In tasks.py file
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def randadd(x):
    y = randint(0,9)
    return x + y

# In views.py 
    context = {
        'add': tasks.randadd(5)
    }
def home(request):
    global context
    return render(request, "home.html", context)

# In home.html
<h1>{{ add }}</h1>
```

In home.html I see the result of 5 + (a random int). How would I recalculate the result for add so that its value is updated every 30 minutes?

I was able to find this source: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html, but I am still confused on how to use it.

Comment: You're a fair way off here. Firstly, instead of returning a value from randadd you should be storing in a data store somewhere. Your view then should load this value to display it. Beat is Celery's built in tool to regularly trigger tasks.

Comment: I see, can you show me how or suggest a link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a shell implementation using Redis as a data store. It assumes Redis is installed and running on the local machine with default settings.

```
# tasks.py
import redis
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def update_number():
    r = redis.StrictRedis()
    r.set('my_number', randint(0,9))


# views.py
import redis

def home(request):
    r = redis.StrictRedis()
    context = {
        'add': r.get('my_number')
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)


# settings.py
from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'context': {
        'task': 'tasks.update_number',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=30),
    }
}
```

Be sure to check the celery docs on the following:

- Configure a message queue (Redis can be used as a message queue)
- Run a celery worker
- Run a celery beat instance

Comment: Is there an equivalent way of storing data with rabbitmq?  For instance you used redis.StrictRedis() to store randint(0,9) in 'my_number'.

Comment: No, RabbitMQ doesn't offer storage. An alternative to using Redis would be a database, such as PostgreSQL. In the Django world, you would create a Model to read and write to the database.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I was able to solve my issue thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs you referenced, it looks like this is one way:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'context': {
        'task': 'randadd',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=30),
        'args': 5
        # or if that doesn't work try:
        #'args':(5)
    },
}
```

And this is another:

```
from datetime import timedelta

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'context': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        'schedule': timedelta(minutes=30),
        'args': 5
        #but the last line still might be:
        #'args':(5)
    },
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work.  I think the doc that I've referenced is just calling the function every 30 seconds, but I want the data stored in 'add' to  update periodically.